# Using foldr with only two parameters

Tags: haskell, fold

I've got a few exercises to prepare for the exam in Haskell/Prolog.

One Haskell task is to rewrite the function below:

```
original :: [Integer] -> Integer
original [] = 0
original (x:xs) | x < 20    = 5 * x - 3 + original xs
                | otherwise = original xs
```

But the condition is that I am only allowed to remove the two "undifined" in the scheme below:

```
alternative :: [Integer] -> Integer
alternative = foldr undefined undefined
```

My problem is that I dont know how this could match the normal foldr structure with 3 parameters (function, "start value" or how is it called?,list)?

Maybe an equivalent example would be helpfull, not the full soultion please!

Futhermore I am not allowed to use "let" or "where".

Thank you for any help!

Sooo... I just followed the idea from @hugo to just first complete the task on the "normal" way, which works but is not allowed by our university correction tool:

```
alternative :: [Integer] -> Integer
alternative list = foldr (\ x y -> if x < 20 then 5*x -3 + y else y) 0 list
```

AND after try end error i got the solution:

```
alternative :: [Integer] -> Integer
alternative = foldr (\ x y -> if x < 20 then 5*x -3 + y else y) 0
```

Comment: Hint: `foldr` is some sort of catamorphism on the list: you can replace `(:)` with the first parameter, and `[]` with the second one, and then you obtain the result of `foldr`.

Comment: Partial application/currying means that whenever you apply a function to one argument, you get back a function taking the remaining arguments. `foldr` has type `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`, so if you give it two parameters (of the appropriate types) you get back a function of type `[a] -> b`, which matches what you're trying to get here.

Comment: `(+) foldr 0` is equivalent to `foldr + 0`, so no, that doesn't make sense. Think about why `evensOnly xs = filter even xs` is equivalent to `evensOnly = filter even` instead.

Comment: Ignoring some subtleties, `alternative = foldr undefined undefined` is equivalent to `alternative x = foldr undefined undefined x`.

Comment: So it seems I need the concept of currying right? And this concept brings me to the statement from @chepner right?

Comment: @rene: How about you start writing the `alternative` function with a fold, ignoring the parameter constraint that you mentioned? Add it to your question and people will help you from there (unless you figure it out along the way, which mey very well happen!)

Comment: @rene Yes, you need to understand currying and partial application. The key idea is that all functions, including `foldr`, take _one_ argument. Some of them happen to return another function, so that can take another argument, and so on. Here `foldr` takes as argument `a->b->b`, and returns `b->[a]->b`. If another argument of type `b` is applied to the result, then we get another result of type `[a]->b`, which matches the type of `alternative`.

Comment: see definition of foldr: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#foldr

Comment: OK now i really got it...For anybody who is interested you shoud look at http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions ... a nice explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list like `[1,4,2,5]` is syntactical sugar for `(:) 1 ((:) 4 ((:) 2 ((:) 5 [])))`. `foldr f z` basically replaces the `(:)` data constructor with `f`, and the empty list data constructor `[]` with `z`. So `foldr f z` will result in `f 1 (f 4 (f 2 (f 5 z)))`.

Since you write `original [] = 0`, this thus means that for `z`, we can use `0`. For `f` we can use `if x < 20 then (+) (5*x-3) else id`, since in case `x < 20`, we add `5*x-3` to the value, and otherwise, we do nothing with the recursively computed value.

We can thus make an `alternative` implementation that looks like:

```
alternative :: (Foldable  f, Num a, Ord a) => f a -> a
alternative = foldr f 0
    where f x ys | x < 20 = 5*x - 3 + ys
                 | otherwise = ys
```

or without the `where` clause with an inline lambda expression:

```
alternative :: (Foldable  f, Num a, Ord a) => f a -> a
alternative = foldr (\x -> if x < 20 then (+) (5*x-3) else id) 0
```